# Yii2 dataprovider not loading GET parameters

Tags: php, yii2

I am trying to setup pagination for Yii2 listView. I am sending `'page'` parameter in GET request, but 0 gets always loaded into `dataprovider->pagination->page` property. When debugging I can see the GET page parameter set correctly, also when trying to set `pageSize` as `'per-page'` GET parameter it works and loads correctly.

My controller code:

```
$searchModel = new WinerySearch();
$dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);   
$dataProvider->pagination->pageSize = $this->pageSize;


if (\Yii::$app->request->isAjax) {

$displayedItems = $dataProvider->pagination->pageSize * ($dataProvider->pagination->page) + $dataProvider->count;
```

0 is always returned by `$dataProvider->pagination->page`

Ajax request code:

```
var pageNumber = 1;
$.ajax({
        method: 'GET',
        url: url+"?page="+pageNumber,
        success: function(data, textStatus, request){
```

Answer (score 0):

Insert

```
<?php var_dump($dataProvider->pagination->page); ?>
<?php var_dump($dataProvider->pagination); ?>
```

at the bottom of one of your grids or lists on the index page. The var_dump always returns a value one less than the page number if you refresh the page manually. I used a pageSize of 1. I noticed also that it can remain dormant ie. on its current value even with page changes via the pagination buttons and not via a refresh.

[Consider perhaps this code:](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/data/Pagination.php)

```
public function getPage($recalculate = false)
{
    if ($this->_page === null || $recalculate) {
        $page = (int) $this->getQueryParam($this->pageParam, 1) - 1;
        $this->setPage($page, true);
    }

    return $this->_page;
}
```

[Or perhaps considering reworking this code:](https://github.com/pcrt/yii2-ajax-pager)

```
$dataProvider->pagination = [
        'pageSize'=>$pageSize,
        'page'=>$pageNumber-1,
];
```